# How to convert traditional form of piecewise output into input piecewise function?

Tags: piecewise, mathematica-online

I have an output in this form. Let's say the f[s_,t_]:=output;  When I try to calculate points at s, t e.g f[0.1,0.1], the output is still the same instead of any point.
[image]

but if I convert this output manually into a new function PdfPiecewise[s_,t_]:=expression; and put values of s and t  PdfPiecewise[0.1,0.1] then I got any value.
[image]

Is there any way to automatically convert Piecewise output into Piecewise input because it's hard to do manually every time with new output piecewise expression?

Comment: Please provide all the Mathematica code in plain text format. Also show the actual call you made. Not just function definition. Basically all the code needed to reproduce the problem in plain text format. No one is going to be able to copy code from an image.  But have you tried `InputForm` on the output in question?

Comment: You might try `f[s_,t_] := Evaluate[output]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we have a piecewise function:

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[{{-1, t < 0}, {1, t >= 0}}];
```

Its output form is:

[image]

Assume you have only the output form. You may easily convert it to the input form by:

[image]

This results in:

```
Piecewise[{{-1, t < 0}, {1, t >= 0}}, 0]
```

With this you may define a new function:

[image]

```
f[1]
(* 1 *)
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you.